# Elastic5.4: How to track completion of delete index?

Tags: elasticsearch, listener, indices

I am using the Java API for ES5.4.1 (I cannot upgrade to a newer version) as

```
DeleteIndexResponse delResp = indicesClient.prepareDelete(indices).get();
```

The problem is that the index is very large, so delResp.isAcknowledged() could be false, because all nodes have not responded. As in https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-delete-acknowledgement/10112. 
Because of the way my code is setup, I **cannot** use listeners. So  cannot use-

```
indicesClient.prepareDelete(indexName).execute(new ActionListener<DeleteIndexResponse>() 
{
  @Override
  public void onResponse(DeleteIndexResponse response) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Exception e) {
  }
});
```

Is there any other way to find out if the delete on the indices is complete? Will checking cluster health status (on whether it is green or yellow) work? (I don't know if the status becomes red while deleting)